# Flow error only in managed package with Apex actions returning data

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, apexactionfunction

I have a simple flow who calls an Apex action and then tries to use the returned value.
Here is the Apex method :

```
@InvocableMethod(label='CheckInstall' description='Check registration' category='MyObject')
public static List<CheckResult> checkRegistration(){
    List<CheckResult> lb = new List<CheckResult>();
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = getHttpRequest();
    req.setEndPoint(endpoint + '/orgs/' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    if (res.getStatusCode()==200)
    {
        System.debug(res.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> resp = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        lb.add( new CheckResult(resp.get('data') != null ));
    }
    else lb.add(new CheckResult(false));
    System.debug('checkInstall returns ' + lb);
    return lb;
}

global class CheckResult {
    @InvocableVariable
    public Boolean result;
    public CheckResult(Boolean b){
        this.result = b;
    }
}
```

Now in my flow I just have

- a Boolean variable called firstCheckResult
- this apex action called firstCheck
- an assignation called getResult that puts check.result into firstCheckResult

[image: my flow]

In the scratch org where I made the flow, everything works fine. But once packaged in a managed package and deployed in another scratch org, the flow fails to assign the variable.
Yet the log in developer console shows that my apex action is returning what I expect :

```
08:27:47:140 USER_DEBUG [196]|DEBUG|checkInstall returns (CheckResult:[result=false])
...
08:27:47:198 FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).|FlowAssignment|getResult
```

Here are the assignment and the variable definition

```
<assignments>
    <name>getResult</name>
    <label>getResult</label>
    <locationX>176</locationX>
    <locationY>278</locationY>
    <assignmentItems>
        <assignToReference>firstCheckResult</assignToReference>
        <operator>Assign</operator>
        <value>
            <elementReference>firstCheck.result</elementReference>
        </value>
    </assignmentItems>
</assignments>
<variables>
    <name>firstCheckResult</name>
    <dataType>Boolean</dataType>
    <isCollection>false</isCollection>
    <isInput>false</isInput>
    <isOutput>false</isOutput>
</variables>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Changing the method to return a List<Boolean> instead of a List<CheckResult> and then assigning firstCheck instead of firstCheck.result solved my problem. However it still looks like a bug and I'm curious to know more about that. My usecase just required a boolean but what if I wanted a more complex return, like a boolean + status + message... ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a salesforce bug, as I've encountered the same issue when deploying as a managed package as well.

For me, manually assigning the output variables from the invokable apex action, allowed references to these in later flow elements.

[image: Screenshot of manually assigned output variables from apex action]

[image: Decision flow element referencing output variable instead of auto-assigned result]